# how to pass an array to function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I wish to pass an array to a function(can you tell me if im on the right track?)

and then in the function I wish to loop through the values in an array and append each one into the following LI element in HTML

This is what I have so far a user will code in the URL values he wants to pass:

```
var arrValues = ['http://imgur.com/gallery/L4CmrUt', 'http://imgur.com/gallery/VQEsGHz'];
calculate_image(arrValues);

function calculate_image(arrValues) {
    // Loop over each value in the array.
    var jList = $('.thumb').find('href');
    $.each(arrValues, function(intIndex, objValue) {
        // Create a new LI HTML element out of the
        // current value (in the iteration) and then
        // add this value to the list.
        jList.append($(+ objValue +));
    });
}
}
```

HTML

```
<li>
    <a class="thumb" href="" title="Title #13"><img src="" alt="Title #13" /></a>
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="download">
            <a href="">Download Original</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-title">Title #13</div>
        <div class="image-desc">Description</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: global variables are already accessible to functions, why you need to pass it in ??

Comment: jQuery != javascript. jQuery is just a library.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you have or are you just looking for a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: var jList = $('.thumb').find('href'); Tries to find all href elements inside the .thumb element. It seems your trying to add multiple arguments (href) to a single <a> tag. You need to create an <a> element for each URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'd like to pass in an array, simply put it in as a parameter. In Javascript, you can pass numbers, strings, arrays, objects, and even functions in as parameters.

See this example for a thumbnail builder implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/RxHys/9/

First, define the arrays.

```
var bluearray = [
    'http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs30/f/2008/056/8/0/Purple_hair___Bipasha_Basu_by_mstrueblue.jpg',
    'http://static.becomegorgeous.com/img/arts/2010/Feb/20/1805/purple_hair_color.jpg',
    'http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/6916/celenapurpleqp7.jpg'
    ];
var greenarray = [
    'http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7fqmkNEhc1qlfspwo1_400.jpg',
    'http://www.haircolorsideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/green-red-hair.jpg',
    'http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2010/011/9/c/Neon_Yellow_and_Green_Hair_by_CandyAcidHair.jpg'
    ];
```

Then when the DOM is loaded, call the functions to load the thumbnails.

```
$(function() {
    addThumbs(bluearray);
    addThumbs2(greenarray);
});
```

addThumbs uses jQuery's each function to make things a bit cleaner. I find it looks better and is nicer to use that the normal Javascript for loop.

```
function addThumbs(paths) {
    $.each(paths,function(index, value) {
        $("div").append('<img src="' + value + '" />');
    });
}
```

But if you're a fan of native Javascript, the normal for loop is implemented in addThumbs2

```
function addThumbs2(paths) {
    for(index in paths) {
        $("div").append('<img src="' + paths[index] + '" />');
    }
}
```